# Java superclass user for logging in

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, servlets, superclass

I'm having some problems with my superclass User that contains the username and password of a student, teacher and company.

Everything works fine, but when I log in with a certain username/password combination the data gets lost. I still have the data from student/teacher/company but no longer the User data.

**User.java** (gebruiker in dutch, this is the superclass):

```
public class Gebruiker {
private String gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord;

public Gebruiker(String gn, String ww) {
    gebruikersnaam = gn; //username
    wachtwoord = ww; //password
}

public Gebruiker() { 
    //Default constructor
}

    //Getters and setters...
}
}
```

**Student.java** (leerling in dutch):

```
public class Leerling extends Gebruiker implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3586223028920551117L;
private String naam, email, leerlingnr;

public Leerling(String gn, String ww, String nm, String em, String ln) {
    super(gn, ww);
    naam = nm;
    email = em;
    leerlingnr = ln;
}

    //Getters and setters...
}
```

Up until this point the code works fine. I can create a student with a username and password like this:

```
Gebruiker g1 = (Gebruiker) new Leerling("username", "password", "name", "email", "nr");
```

The problem comes when I login into my application and set the session with my user:

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("gebruikerObject", g1);
```

The moment I refresh the page. The username and password from the user object are null, 'name' 'email' and 'nr' stay normal. When I print gebruikerObject on my JSP page, I get an different return value every refresh:

```
com.appspot.AccentNijkerk.model.Leerling@16ee9e2
com.appspot.AccentNijkerk.model.Leerling@1c6b2e3
com.appspot.AccentNijkerk.model.Leerling@1fa486
```

I really hope you guys can help me out, thanks in advance.

*PS: Im using Google App Engine, sessions are enabled*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Gebruiker` should be serializable as well.

Also, you should learn about the `this` keyword, and use it to have good, readable, understandable variable names, respecting the Java naming conventions:

```
public Gebruiker(String gebruikersNaam, String wachtWoord) {
    this.gebruikersNaam = gebruikersNaam;
    this.wachtWoord = wachtWoord;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, working perfect! Will accept your answer in a few minutes, can't do that yet.